How to use ARM template spec?
I had tried to deploy some resources at once using linked template format, but it was failed because my storage account is only allowed private access.
So I want to deploy using template spec but I don't know how to use it.
Here is main_template.json.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "storage",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "uri": "https://test/Storage/linkedtemplate_storage.json",
                  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                  "uri": "https://test/Storage/linkedtemplate_storage.parameters-dev.json",
                  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "monitoring",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "uri": "https://test/Monitoring/linkedtemplate_monitoring.json",
                  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                  "uri": "https://test/Monitoring/linkedtemplate_monitoring.parameters-dev.json",
                  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "notification",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "uri": "https://test/Notification/linkedtemplate_notification.json",
                  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                  "uri": "https://test/Notification/linkedtemplate_notification.parameters-dev.json",
                  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

As you can see, I want to use a parameter file for each linked template which is stored in the storage account.
However, referring to the MS documentation, I am not sure that I can use the URI of linked template which is stored in storage account that only allows private access.
Anyone can resolve this problem?
Any answer would be helped.
Thank you.

you can use template specs for this refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs?tabs=azure-powershell @Cuteeeerabbit

you need to create a template spec in azure first. then use its uri in template.


Use of ARM template spec

You need to make use of template spec to store your linked templates instead of relying on the URIs from the storage account.

Here you provided the URLs of the storage account, and its private storage account will not have enough privilages.
First create the Template Spec for each of your linked templates
az ts create --name "storage-template" --version "1.0.0" --location "eastus" --template-file "./linkedtemplate_storage.json"

Similarly follow the same for rest of the templates.
democonfiguration:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
      "name": "storageDeployment",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "https://<yourstorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/templates/linkedtemplate_storage.json?<SAStoken>",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
          },
          "location": {
            "value": "[parameters('location')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

since your storage account in private make sure you passed the SAS token to have necessary provision permission.
Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs-deploy-linked-template?tabs=azure-powershell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs-create-linked?tabs=azure-powershell
